# Juxtaposition of terms in ML

Tags: functional-programming, ml

I'm trying to translate the following piece of code:

```
(* elim: vname * term * (term * term) list * subst -> subst *)
and elim(x,t,S,s) =
      if occurs x t then raise UNIFY
      else let val xt = lift [(x,t)]
           in solve(map (fn (t1,t2) => (xt t1, xt t2)) S,
                    (x,t) :: (map (fn (y,u) => (y, xt u)) s))
end;
```

coming form [this repository](https://github.com/andy-morris/andallthat/blob/bf1c6c4ff7277db4f1706ff226e00ffe900671c1/trs.ML) into another language. My problem comes because I don't know exactly what is the semantics of `(xt t1, xt t2)`
 in ML. In principle `xt,t1,t2` are terms so i imagine that `xt t1` should be some sort of concatenation (althougth there is no concatenation defined).

What does this code mean in ML?

For completeness here is the rest of the relevant definitions:

```
type vname = string * int;
type subst = (vname * term) list;
datatype term = V of vname | T of string * term list;

(* lift: subst -> term -> term *)
(* indom: vname -> subst -> bool *)
(* solve: (term * term)list * subst -> subst *)
```

Comment: Juxtaposition is function application.

Comment: @molbdnilo however, what does it mean in this context to apply a term to a term?

Comment: `xt` is not a `term`, it's a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juxtaposition is function application.
 `(a,b)` is a pair.

As you can see from the type of `lift`, `lift [(x,t)]` – that is, `xt`– is a function `term -> term`.

Thus, `(xt t1, xt t2)` is a pair `term * term`, whose first element is the result of applying `xt`to `t1`, and whose second element is `xt` applied to `t2`.